# Generate dynamic value when added new field

Tags: php, jquery

I am adding new table row dynamically using jQuery. It adds successfully, now I want to pull each record dynamically depending on dropdown value and show in multiple divs. All works fine if the table row is only one, but when I add new row using jQuery it does not increment the counter value due to this. When I select dropdown value from second row it does not pull record against it.

```
    function add_allowance() {
    
    var click = 2;
    jQuery("#addrows").click(function(){
        jQuery('#maintable tr:last').after('<tr class="tablechild"><td><select name="empallownacename" id="allowancename" class="select2_category form-control"><option value="none" selected="selected">-Select-</option></select></td><td><input type="text" name="empmount" value="" class="form-control"  /></td><td><input type="text" name="empdescription" value="" class="form-control"  /></td><td><a style="cursor: pointer;" value="Remove" class="minusbtn" id="remove"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></td></tr>');
    });
    click++;
}

   

    <tr class="tablechild">
    <td>
        <select name="allowancename<?php echo $counter; ?>" id="allowancename" class="select2_category form-control">
            <option>-Select-</option>
            <?php foreach($allowances as $allowance):?>
            <option value="<?php echo $allowance['id']; ?>"><?php echo $allowance['name'];?></option>
               <?php $counter; ?>
             <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" id="allowanceamount" name="allowanceamount" value="" class="form-control"  /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="allowancedesc" name="allowancedesc" value="" class="form-control"  /></td>
    <td>
        <a style="cursor: pointer;" value="Remove" class="minusbtn" id="remove"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you clicks, The method is called and it initialize the variable by 2 always. It is not good practice. you can do as follows:
 function add_allowance() {

```
    var click;
    jQuery("#addrows").click(function(){
        jQuery('#maintable tr:last').after('<tr class="tablechild"><td><select name="empallownacename" id="allowancename" class="select2_category form-control"><option value="none" selected="selected">-Select-</option></select></td><td><input type="text" name="empmount" value="" class="form-control"  /></td><td><input type="text" name="empdescription" value="" class="form-control"  /></td><td><a style="cursor: pointer;" value="Remove" class="minusbtn" id="remove"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></td></tr>');
    });
    click=$('table tr).length; // It will count number of rows in the table and return integer value no of rows
}
```